# C# equivalent of /Gh flag

Tags: c#, windows

The [/Gh compiler flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c63a9b7h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) allows you to hook all C/C++ functions in your library. Is there an equivalent C# way ?

Comment: Not knowing what `_penter` does, can you explain the objective of this flag?

Comment: The only way to achieve is this is via AOP (or maybe the profiler API).

Comment: @Oded _penter allows you to have a callback function called before every C# function

Comment: Thanks for clarifying for the .NET crowd that has no c++ experience.

Comment: What do you want to be able to do at the start *of every function*?

Answer (score 0):

c# have not this flag or something like this flag

but you can call function through wrapper with [func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

or use attribute and write own behavior